# Running an async function fetching a site in a loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, async-await, fetch

Hey guys i am **scraping** a website getting an image url for a movie/
I have these function currently getting the image which is working just fine outside a loop

```
 async function getPosterDB(imdbID) {
  const posterdbURL = "https://www.movieposterdb.com/search?q=";
  let poster = "";
  try {
    return fetch(`${posterdbURL}${imdbID}`)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((body) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        poster = $(
          "body > div.section > div > div > div.col-md-9 > div.pt-3 > div.row.mgrid > div > a > img"
        ).attr("src");
        if (poster) {
          poster = poster.replace("posters", "xl");
          poster = poster.replace("/s", "/xl");
        }
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return poster;
}
```

The thing is when i try to get the url running through a loop . i get undefined or a promise
Now i searched on the web and found out i should use either a setTimeout function to delay the function or either Promise.all() , maybe i am missing something out
The code which is the function is here.

```
async function advancedSearchMovies(searchTerm) {
  const movies = [];
  let images = [];
  try {
    return await fetch(`${MovieAdvancedUrl}${searchTerm}`)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then(async (body) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $("#main > div > div.lister.list.detail.sub-list > div >").each(
          async function (i, elem) {
            let imdbID = $(elem)
              .find("div.lister-item-image.float-left > a")
              .attr("href")
              .match(/title\/(.*)\//)[1];
          
            )
              let poster = getPosterDB(imdbID)
              const movie = {
                imdbID: imdbID,
                title: title,
                poster
              };

              movies.push(movie);
            }
          }
        );
        const result = Promise.all(movies).then(data => { return data});
        return result;
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

But i still get a promise back , any idea ?

> {
> imdbID: 'tt1185834',
> title: 'Star Wars: The Clone Wars',
> yearRun: '2008',
> ratingIMDB: '5.9',
> ratingMeta: '35',
> summary: "After the Republic's victory on Christophsis, Anakin and his new apprentice Ahsoka Tano must rescue the kidnapped son of Jabba the Hutt. Political intrigue complicates their mission.",
> **poster: Promise { pending }**
> }

PROBLEM FIXED :
I just made the function return a promise

```
async function getPosterDB(imdbID) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fetch(`${posterdbURL}${imdbID}`)
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((body) => {
      const $ = cheerio.load(body);
      poster = $(
        "body > div.section > div > div > div.col-md-9 > div.pt-3 > div.row.mgrid > div > a > img"
      ).attr("src");
      if (poster) {
        poster = poster.replace("posters", "xl");
        poster = poster.replace("/s", "/xl");
      }
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(poster);
      }, 1000);
    });
});
}
```

and then when i call it like this:

```
const images = await Promise.all(
          movies.map((element) =>
            getPosterDB(element.imdbID).then((data) => {
              return data;
            })
          )
        );
        movies.forEach((element, index) => {
          element.poster = images[index];
        });
        return movies;
      });
```

Comment: The second version looks fine, and as you observed it returns a Promise. So just call `.then(...)` on the result.

Comment: PS the `.then(data => { return data})` does nothing and therefore can be removed.

Comment: adding another .then ( (final) => console.log(final)) gives undefined

Answer (score 1):

You need to put promises inside the array that you're passing to `Promise.all`. You're only pushing movie objects, and you're doing that asynchronously, so when you call `Promise.all` the array is still unpopulated.

Also I'd recommend to avoid using `.then()` calls when working with `async`/`await`:

```
async function advancedSearchMovies(searchTerm) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`${MovieAdvancedUrl}${searchTerm}`);
    const body = await response.text();
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);
    const promises = Array.from($("#main > div > div.lister.list.detail.sub-list > div >")).map(async elem => {
      const imdbID = $(elem)
        .find("div.lister-item-image.float-left > a")
        .attr("href")
        .match(/title\/(.*)\//)[1];
      const poster = await getPosterDB(imdbID)
      const movie = {
        imdbID,
        title,
        poster,
      };
      return movie;
    });
    const movies = await Promise.all(promises);
    return movies;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Notice that you should not use `try`/`catch` syntax if you cannot really handle the error. Logging it and returning `undefined` is probably not what the caller of your function expects. Better let the exception bubble.

Regarding `getPosterDB`, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

```
async function getPosterDB(imdbID) {
  const response = await fetch(`${posterdbURL}${imdbID}`);
  const body = await response.text();
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  let poster = $(
    "body > div.section > div > div > div.col-md-9 > div.pt-3 > div.row.mgrid > div > a > img"
  ).attr("src");
  if (poster) {
    poster = poster.replace("posters", "xl");
    poster = poster.replace("/s", "/xl");
  }
  return poster;
}
```

Comment: Still getting either a promise back and when i resolve it i get undefined.Tried also to pass an array of all the promises made during the loop still nothing.